# Success transaction of Ethereum not reflecting in my coinbase wallet

Tags: blockchain, coinbase

I transferred ethereum of 0.074 to my coinbase wallet. it is showing success transaction but it is not reflecting in my coinbase wallet, why?

Comment: If you mean Coinbase the exchange then it can be due to various reasons - if it has been mined then it's stuck in some exchange's internal processes probably. Would help if you clarify your question - do you mean the exchange? And can you provide the transaction hash (or link in Etherscan)?

Comment: it is fixed now.